# Most efficient way to print an AVL tree of strings?

Tags: string, data-structures, tree, big-o, avl-tree

I'm thinking that an in order traversal will run in O(n) time. The only thing better than that would be to have something running in logn time. But I don't see how this could be, considering we have to run at least n times.

Is O(n) the lastest we could do here?

Comment: So if you have N nodes, you can't execute N prints faster than O(N) (not counting threading etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Converting and expanding @C.B.'s comment to an answer:

If you have an AVL tree with n strings in it and you want to print all of them, then you have to do at least Θ(n) total work simply because you have to print out each of the n strings. You can often lower-bound the amount of work required to produce a list or otherwise output a sequence of values simply by counting up how many items are going to be in the list.

We can be even more precise here. Suppose the combined length of all the strings in the tree is L. The time required to print out all the strings in the tree has to be at least Θ(L), since it costs some computational effort to output each individual character. Therefore, we can say that we have to do at least Θ(n + L) work to print out all the strings in the tree.

The bound given here just says that any correct algorithm has to do at least this much work, not that there actually is an algorithm that does this much work. But if you look closely at any of the major tree traversals - inorder, preorder, postorder, level-order - you'll find that they all match this time bound.

Now, one area where you can look for savings is in space complexity. A level-order traversal of the tree might require Ω(n) total space if the tree is perfectly balanced (since it holds a whole layer of the tree in memory and the bottommost layer can have Θ(n) nodes in it), while an inorder, preorder, or postorder traversal would only require O(log n) memory because you only need to store the current access path, which has logarithmic height in an AVL tree.